# Как ловить ошибку упавшего/не запущеного воркера dramatiq?

Tags: python, django

django_dramatiq не кидает исключения при вызове actor и не запущенном воркере. Как отлавливать такое?

Функция не выполняется, исключения не кидает.

```
@dramatiq.actor
def do_somthing():
    print("Async task")
```

Comment: Имеется ввиду что вы пытаетесь вызвать `do_somthing` при это не запуская `python manage.py rundramatiq`?

Comment: Да, один из вариантов. Как на стороне django понять, что он запущен/работает или нет?

Comment: ну как я понимаю информацию по запущенным работникам нужно уточнять у брокера. с драматик не работал

Comment: Ваша функция изначально отправляется в очередь и никакого отношения к воркеру не имеет. Как только воркер будет запущен то он заберет её с очереди и выполнит. Как проверить запущен ли воркер через АПИ я не нашел

Comment: Спасибо, это я знаю, ну вот я тоже смотрел документацию и не увидел(